# A small alteration to the Afshar experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I found a setup of Afshar experiment in Fig. 3 of this Wikipedia link. I assume that the setup shown in Fig.3 is accurate (Sorry for using Wiki as a link).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afshar_experiment

[image]

My understanding of the experiment is: When both slits are open and the wires are in place, you get no blocking of light by the wires. When you close one of the slit, some light is blocked by the wires.

My question: What happens when both slits are open & the wires are in place, but one of the detectors is turned off? This turning off process may be performed before the experiment takes place, during the experiment, or randomly. Will turning one of the detector on/off in the experiment change the outcome?

Common sense says no. Empirically? I don't know.

Disclosure: I have a QM interpretation which I favor. I am trying to test it by asking this question. But my favored opinions don't (and shouldn't) matter to Science. If the experiment remains unaffected, just say no. If the experiment is affected, say how its affected.